# Convert integer value into years, months, weeks and days

Tags: php

I am working on a task where I need to convert given integer value which is total number of months into year, months,weeks and days

For example if the given value is `62` months then i should be able to take this number and convert it into `x years x months x weeks and x days`

I can find several examples online that take 2 dates and give you the required output but my requirement is to take the number and convert that into years, months, weeks, days.

I will really appreciate if someone can point me to the right direction.

Comment: With no reference date, it's impossible to know how many weeks and days a certain number of months is because the number of days in a month is not consistent. You need to make it clear exactly how you want the numbers to be calculated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to get a completely accurate result, considering not all months are equal. Without knowing which months and from which years, the closest you can get is an approximation, using simple math:

```
$months = 62;

$days = $months*30; //or 28 or 31 or 29(leap year)
$weeks = $months*4; //or $days/7;
$years = $months/12; //or floor($months/12) . ' years and ' . $months%12 . ' months'
```

[**See demo**](http://codepad.org/WQhA9L9s)

Comment: Thanks, i think this might be what i am looking for, will get back to you shortly.

Comment: Note: I'd base the weeks on the number of days / 7 if you want anything like consistent results... :)

Comment: this is close to what i need, the output should be 5 years and 1 month and x days because this is what equals to `62` months

Comment: Just math. 62 months is approximately 5 years and 2 months. (60/12 = 5 and 60%12 = 2)

Comment: just math dont solve the "issue" a month can have eg. 31 days too or i am wrong?

Comment: @ins0 Of course - that was explicitly stated in my answer. Ultimately this is an issue that is impossible to solve - also stated in my answer. The point here is to make an *approximation*. To get `5 years and 2 months` from `62` based on the assumption of 12 months per year, just math is all you need.

Comment: please look at my answer, it is not impossible.

Comment: @Baig For years, you will never have X years X months X days. 62 is an integer so you will always have *only* years and months.

Comment: @ins0 What's not possible? Did you read my answer or my comment?

Comment: please give me sometime, i am looking into it and will get back with what worked

Comment: @Baig for years you can try: `$years = floor($months/12) . ' years and ' . $months%12 . ' months';` [**See demo**](http://codepad.org/yYr4bv8O)

Comment: Thank you so much @MarkM this is exactly what i as looking for. I understand this is not going to be accurate as number of days in a month differ at times but for now this will do. I really appreciate everyone's feedback and assistance in this

Answer (score 5):

"A month" is anything from 28 to 31 days. It cannot be clearly divided into a specific number of days or weeks, because it's an ambiguous timespan to begin with. If you knew an exact start date and a clear specification for "a month", you could get to a result. But simply "62 months" by itself is impossible to convert without a lot more clarification.

Comment: lets suppose every month is 31 days, then how can it be achieved?

Comment: Simple multiplication and division.

Comment: a simple multiplication is close to what i need but not exactly what i need, suppose the month is `52` what i am looking for as an out put is 4 year, 4 months as this is `52` months

Comment: Still simple math. Divide by 12 to get the years. Round it. Subtract from the month number to get **the remainder**. That's your months. Multiply further to get weeks/days. Always round and subtract to get **the remainder**.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the php built in `DateTime` functions, `strtotime` do get the results you are looking for in a nice clean format.

http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.diff.php

https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.strtotime.php

```
$months = 62;
$dateTime = new DateTime();
$newDateTime = $dateTime->diff(
    new DateTime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime(sprintf('-%s Months', $months))))
);

print_R($newDateTime);
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 5
    [m] => 2
    [d] => 0
    [h] => 0
    [i] => 0
    [s] => 0
    [weekday] => 0
    [weekday_behavior] => 0
    [first_last_day_of] => 0
    [invert] => 1
    [days] => 1887
    [special_type] => 0
    [special_amount] => 0
    [have_weekday_relative] => 0
    [have_special_relative] => 0
)
```

Comment: You can taking date into consideration, as stated in the question i only have one integer number to work with which is `month`

Comment: i am looking into it and will get back to you